# check duplicate record

Tags: php, mysql

How do I check duplicate records in MySQL?
My cronjob runs every minute.
So every minute I insert the same result in MySQL.
How do I ensure that only non-dublicate records get inserted into the database and duplicate records are refused.

here is my code:

```
if($trim != $yesterdayresult){                                              
  while($user = mysql_fetch_array($checklist)){
    $usernumber = $user['msisdn'];
    $usertelco = $user['telco'];
    $userkw = $user['kw'];
    $usersc = $user['shortcode'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO mt_log 
             VALUES 
             ('','$Currentdatetime','$usernumber','$usertelco','$finalresult'
             ,'$userkw','$usersc','$price')");
  }
} else {echo "Results have not updated yet, please wait";}
```

Comment: How can be defined the duplicity in this record?
Write list of column(s) by which you do specify duplicit row

Comment: I'm having a **really** hard time understanding what you wrote... I can mostly understand it if I ignore parts of the text and just guess what you want

Comment: Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1):

> my cronjob must running every minute

You're running a cronjob every minute? This is not a very good idea. While these days it would be reasonable to expect an average jitter in the range of a few seconds on a dedicated machine, it still entails additional controls to manage runtime overlaps - particularly if you're using ISAM data tables. If processing is required this frequently a daemon process would be much more reliable.

> how to check duplicate record in mysql

I don't see how your code is checking for duplicates. And what do you want to do if you find a duplicate?

If you don't want duplicated records in your database then create a unique key on the fields which would cause the record to be a duplicate, then use 'INSERT' and handle a ER_DUP_KEY error or 'INSERT IGNORE' or 'REPLACE' or 'INSERT....ON DUPLICATE....'

> I must insert all the record in mysql then another minute it would not insert again.

So you need a unique index on a new column storing (NOW() - INTERVAL SECOND() SECOND)

However it sounds like you are creating a non-normalized database - which again is a bad practice. There are reasons for denormalizing a database, particularly with regard to pre-consolidation of results - but at 1 minute resolution you're not going to get any performance benefit.

Looking at the actual code you've provided this looks like some sort of telco billing application - in which case the way you are doing your metering completely wrong - you should only log the start and end time for each call.

(BTW relying on column order/number for a DML operation, rather than explicitly stating what columns the values map to on any relational database is sloppy too).

Answer (score 1):

**Preventing duplicate rows in MySQL**

If you want to prevent insertion of duplicate records, you specify a `UNIQUE` index on the combination of fields that you want to be unique.

```
ALTER TABLE mt_log ADD UNIQUE INDEX ui_indexname (column1, column2);
```

After that MySQL will reject any duplicate rows.

**Proper way to insert in MySQL**

I suggest you name the columns explicitly:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mt_log (columname1, columnname2, .....) VALUES (.....)
```

The `IGNORE` part ignores error, so that if you insert multiple rows in one go and you have duplicates in the first row (but not the second) it will not stop, but just ignore the first insert and continue on to the second.

If you want to not specify a values for a column, don't insert `''`, but use `null`.

**If you want to overwrite on duplicate rows**

If you want the duplicate row to always reflect the latest data, do:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mtlog (columnname1, columnname2, ...) 
VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 SET non_duplicate_columnname = '$value1', non_duplicate_columnname2 = '$value2'
```

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html